# Custom-defined functionals in Gaussian 09

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

As [stated before](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39411/definition-of-the-b3lyp-functional-in-common-qc-programs) I want to try out custom-defined functionals. Besides the question about B3LYP itself, there is another related question.

Short excerpt:

> $$\text{XC-Functional}=a E_x^\text{local}+(1-a)E_x^\text{HF}+b E_x^\text{non-local}+c E_c^\text{non-local}+(1-c) E_c^\text{local}$$
>
> The Gaussian documentation for DFT inputs specifies how one could change the amounts of each "sub-functional" by using the IOp-Statements through:
>
> IOp(3/76=mmmmmnnnnn) IOp(3/77=mmmmmnnnnn) IOp(3/78=mmmmmnnnnn)
>
> Where `mmmmm` and `nnnnn` will get divided by 10000 and `3/76`=$P_1P_2$, `3/77`=$P_3P_4$ and `3/88`=$P_5P_6$. Those $P_{1,..,6}$ values are part of the following equation, which is a modified version of the equation above.
>
> $$\text{XC-Functional}=P_2 E_X^\text{HF} + P_1 \left(P_4 E_X^\text{Slater} + P_3\Delta E_x^\text{non-local}\right) + P_6 E_C^\text{local} + P_5 \Delta E_C^\text{non-local}$$

Now [Gaussian's description site about DFT](http://gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/k_dft.htm) tells that one simply has to choose one exchange and one correlation functional, i.e. B and LYP. But then B would be used for $E_x^\text{non-local}$ and LYP probably for $E_c^\text{non-local}$.

Does that mean, that the $E_c^\text{local}$-part

- cannot be defined,
- is always the VWN functional as in B3LYP, or
- is also the chosen correlation functional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [IOp manual](http://www.gaussian.com/g_tech/g_iops/iops2.pdf). Under IOp(3/74),

> **IOp(3/74)** Type of exchange and correlation potentials.
>
> - **-5** Becke3 using VWN/LYP for correlation.
> - **02** Lee-Yang-Parr correlation.
> - **05** VWN 80 (LSD) correlation.
> - **200** Hartree-Fock-Slater exchange (Alpha = 2/3).
> - **400** Becke 1988 exchange.
>
> So 100 is Hartree-Fock, 200 is Hartree-Fock-Slater, 205 is Local Spin Density, and 402 is BLYP.

They're unclear about it, but this means you can take the "sum" of a 1- or 2-digit number (which specifies the correlation) and a 3- or 4-digit number (which specifies the exchange) to build an exchange-correlation functional. So, `IOp(3/74=-5) == IOp(3/74=402)`, and an identical way to define B3LYP is

`IOp(3/74=402) IOp(3/76=1000002000) IOp(3/77=0720008000) IOp(3/78=0810010000)`

> Does that mean, that the $E_{c}^{\text{local}}$-part
>
> - cannot be defined,
> - is always the VWN functional as in B3LYP, or
> - is also the chosen correlation functional?

Looking at the available correlation functionals (incomplete, these are the lowest few),

- **01** VWN5
- **02** LYP
- **03** P81 (PL in keyword list)
- **04** P81 + P86
- **05** VWN3
- **06** VWN3 + P86
- **07** OS1
- **08** PW91
- **09** PBE
- **10** VSXC
- **11** Bc96
- **18** VWN5 + P86
- **19** LYP + VWN5 for scaling

your choices for *local* correlation functionals are rather limited. Either you choose a correlation functional that's purely local (VWN3, VWN5, or P81), or a non-local/gradient-corrected functional which in Gaussian all seem to have the local component as part of their definition (as in LYP), or they're forcibly combined (as in P86).