# Defining the Turbomole named BP86 functional in Gaussian

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, density-functional-theory

According to Turbomole, the BP86 density functional has the following definition:

$$
\mathrm{Exchange = LDA + B88\\
Correlation = LDA(VWN(V)) + P86}
$$

What is the equivalent definition in Gaussian using `IOp` keywords?

Answer (score 3):

From the Gaussian 09 manual:

> User-Defined Models. Gaussian 09 can use any model of the general form:
>       P2EXHF + P1(P4EXSlater + P3ΔExnon-local) + P6EClocal + P5ΔECnon-local
>
> The only available local exchange method is Slater (S), which should be used when only local exchange is desired. Any combinable non-local exchange functional and combinable correlation functional may be used (as listed previously).
>
> The values of the six parameters are specified with various non-standard options to the program:
>
> - IOp(3/76=mmmmmnnnnn) sets P1 to mmmmm/10000 and P2 to nnnnn/10000. P1 is usually set to either 1.0 or 0.0, depending on whether an exchange functional is desired or not, and any scaling is accomplished using P3 and P4.
> - IOp(3/77=mmmmmnnnnn) sets P3 to mmmmm/10000 and P4 to nnnnn/10000.
> - IOp(3/78=mmmmmnnnnn) sets P5 to mmmmm/10000 and P6 to nnnnn/10000.
>
> For example, IOp(3/76=1000005000) sets P1 to 1.0 and P2 to 0.5. Note that all values must be expressed using five digits, adding any necessary leading zeros.
>
> Here is a route section specifying the functional corresponding to the B3LYP keyword:
>
> `#P BLYP IOp(3/76=1000002000) IOp(3/77=0720008000) IOp(3/78=0810010000)`
>
> The output file displays the values that are in use:
>
> ```
> IExCor=  402 DFT=T Ex=B+HF Corr=LYP ExCW=0 ScaHFX=  0.200000
> ScaDFX=  0.800000  0.720000  1.000000  0.810000
> ```
>
> where the value of ScaHFX is P2, and the sequence of values given for ScaDFX are P4, P3, P6 and P5.

For BP86 specified normally, this looks like:

```
IExCor=  404 DFT=T Ex=B Corr=P86 ExCW=0 ScaHFX=  0.000000
ScaDFX=  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

Those 3 IOps don't completely define the functional, however, `IOp(3/74)` is also needed. See the `IExCor` field, which corresponds to Becke 1988 exchange (400) combined with Perdew 81 + Perdew 86 correlation (4).

Comment: Hi,thanks . defination of BP86 functional in log file of Gaussian  is the same what you write. but i want to create the combination of Turbomole named BP86 functinal in gaussian with IOP keywords

Comment: I hate to be the guy that says I told zahra so. Consider this answer: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39411/definition-of-the-b3lyp-functional-in-common-qc-programs/65113#65113 . This should clear up the confusion about the displayed notation in TM. Bottom line: TM and Gaussian are in agreement.

Comment: IOP(3/74=418) and ScaDFX=  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000

Comment: The turbomole definition of BP86 (with VWN5 instead of VWN3) is accessible within Gaussian as BVP86. Note that you'd have to redefine Dispersion corrections for this functional.